# Print catcodes in LaTeX with LaTeX3

Tags: latex3, catcodes

I have the following MWE which prints the catcode of every character in the list.

The input method is:

```
\MyList{`+,{`,},`\%,`a}
```

but I want to simplify as follows:

```
\MyList{+,{,},\%,a}
```

Here the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse,expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \catcode_print:n #1 
 {
  The~catcode~of~\tl_to_str:n {#1}~is~\char_value_catcode:n {#1} \par
 }
\NewDocumentCommand { \MyList }
 { > { \SplitList { , } } m }
 { \ProcessList {#1} { \catcode_print:n } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
 \MyList{`+,{`,},`\%,`a}
% \MyList{+,{,},\%,a}
\end{document}
```

EDIT and PS:
I want to inverse the number to get the corresponding character:
For example:
`\tex_number:D A` prints 65. But I want to insert `65` and with the result `A`

Comment: Use `\char_value_catcode:n { \`#1 }` instead of `\char_value_catcode:n { #1 }`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: This was to simple ;-). Do you know a way how to inverse `\tex_number:D `A`. This will print `65`. But I want to insert `65` and want to get `A`. (LaTeX3 solution isn't deprecated ;-) ). Please provide an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not expandably, of course:

```
\def\achar#1{\begingroup\lccode`!=#1\lowercase{\endgroup!}}

\achar{65}
\achar{`A}
\achar{"41}
```

will give

> A A A

But of course

```
\char<number>
```

does the same. The `\achar` technique can be useful if you want to define a macro to expand to the character given by number (with category code 12):

```
\def\achar#1#2{\begingroup\lccode`!=#2\lowercase{\endgroup\def#1{!}}}

\achar\firstA{65}
\achar\secondA{`A}
\achar\thirdA{"41}
\show\firstA \show\secondA \show\thirdA
```

What does `\achar` do? It starts a group where the lowercase correspondent of the exclamation character is set to character `#2` (which is supposed to be a number, in any of the formats TeX allows for specifying an integer constant). This correspondance is maintained by an array (a 256 component vector, in 8 bit TeX, the whole `0x110000` of Unicode for XeTeX and LuaTeX, from `0x0000` to `0x10FFFF`): the *n*-th entry specifies the lowercase correspondent for character number *n*.

When we say `\lowercase{<tokens>}`, TeX performs the substitution of each *character* token with its lowercase correspondent and then inserts back in the input stream the token list so obtained, to be read again. In our case `\endgroup`, `\def` and the first argument to `\achar` are not touched, as they are not character tokens, so only `!` is converted, exactly to the character having the number we specified in the second argument. Notice that TeX still hasn't executed `\endgroup`: it does only when the token list is put back. So the group is closed, the `\lccode` assignment is forgotten and the `\def` is executed.

With `\achar\firstA{65}`, for example, the replacement text for `\firstA` is `A` with category code 12, because `!` has category code 12 and `\lowercase` doesn't change this attribute.

The LaTeX3 code is just the same:

```
\NewDocumentCommand { \achar } { m m }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \char_set_lccode:nn { `! } { #2 }
    \tl_to_lowercase:n { \group_end: \cs_new:Npn #1 { ! } }
  }
```

Comment: GREAT! (as always ;-) ) Do you know the LaTeX3 source too?

Comment: Incidentally, the experimental module `l3str` introduces for internal purposes 256 constant token lists holding each of the bytes: for character codes less than `256`, you can access the corresponding character expandably.

Comment: Will you add also the missing 1113856 for Unicode? :)

Comment: @egreg better a late reply than none: no, I won't add ones for Unicode.  The 256 bytes are useful for all engines when converting from an encoding to another (e.g., UTF-16 for some pdf strings).